# What is the best way to pass a list of functions as argument?

Tags: r, function, parameter-passing

I am looking for advice on the best way to code passing a list of functions as argument.

**What I want to do:**

I would like to pass as an argument a list a functions to apply them to a specific input. And give output name based on those.

**A "reproducible" example**

```
input = 1:5
```

Functions to pass are `mean`, `min`

Expected call:

```
foo(input, something_i_ask_help_for)
```

Expected output:

```
list(mean = 3, min = 1)
```

If it's not perfectly clear, please see my two solutions to have an illustration.

**Solution 1:** Passing functions as arguments

```
foo <- function(input, funs){
  # Initialize output
  output = list()

  # Compute output
  for (fun_name in names(funs)){
    # For each function I calculate it and store it in output
    output[fun_name] = funs[[fun_name]](input)
  }

  return(output)
}

foo(1:5, list(mean=mean, min=min))
```

What I don't like with this method is that we can't call it by doing: `foo(1:5, list(mean, min))`.

**Solution 2:** passing functions names as argument and using get

```
foo2 <- function(input, funs){
  # Initialize output
  output = list()

  # Compute output
  for (fun in funs){
    # For each function I calculate it and store it in output
    output[fun] = get(fun)(input)
  }

  return(output)
}
foo2(1:5, c("mean", "min"))
```

What i don't like with this method is that we are not really passing the function-object as argument.

**My question:**

Both ways works, but I not quite sure which one to choose.

Could you help me by:

- Telling me which one is the best?
- What are the advantages and defaults of each methods?
- Is there a another (better) method

If you need any more information, don't hesitate to ask.

Thanks!

Comment: If you can do without the function `foo` returning a named list, maybe you can get some inspiration with `lapply(funs, function(f) f(input))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Simplifying solutions in question

The first of the solutions in the question requires that the list be named and the second requires that the functions have names which are passed as character strings.  Those two user interfaces could be implemented using the following simplifications.  Note that we add an `envir` argument to `foo2` to ensure function name lookup occurs as expected.  Of those the first seems cleaner but if the functions were to be used interactively and less typing were desired then the second does do away with having to specify the names.

```
foo1 <- function(input, funs) Map(function(f) f(input), funs)
foo1(1:5, list(min = min, max = max)) # test

foo2 <- function(input, nms, envir = parent.frame()) {
    Map(function(nm) do.call(nm, list(input), envir = envir), setNames(nms, nms))
}
foo2(1:5, list("min", "max")) # test
```

Alternately we could build `foo2` on `foo1`:

```
foo2a <- function(input, funs, envir = parent.frame()) {
    foo1(input, mget(unlist(funs), envir = envir, inherit = TRUE))
}
foo2a(1:5, list("min", "max")) # test
```

or base the user interface on passing a formula containing the function names since formulas already incorporate the notion of environment:

```
foo2b <- function(input, fo) foo2(input, all.vars(fo), envir = environment(fo))
foo2b(1:5, ~ min + max) # test
```

### Optional names while passing function itself

However, the question indicates that it is preferred that

- the functions themselves be passed
- names are optional

To incorporate those features the following allows the list to have names or not or a mixture.  If a list element does not have a name then the expression defining the function (usually its name) is used.

We can derive the names from the list's names or when a name is missing we can use the function name itself or if the function is anonymous and so given as its definition then the name can be the expression defining the function.

The key is to use `match.call` and pick it apart.  We ensure that `funs` is a list in case it is specified as a character vector. `match.fun` will interpret functions and character strings naming functions and look them up in the parent frame so we use a `for` loop instead of `Map` or `lapply` in order that we not generate a new function scope.

```
foo3 <- function(input, funs) {
  cl <- match.call()[[3]][-1]
  nms <- names(cl)
  if (is.null(nms)) nms <- as.character(cl)
  else nms[nms == ""] <- as.character(cl)[nms == ""]
  funs <- as.list(funs)
  for(i in seq_along(funs)) funs[[i]] <- match.fun(funs[[i]])(input)
  setNames(funs, nms)
}

foo3(1:5, list(mean = mean, min = "min", sd, function(x) x^2))
```

giving:

```
$mean
[1] 3

$min
[1] 1

$sd
[1] 1.581139

$`function(x) x^2`
[1]  1  4  9 16 25
```

Comment: `foo3` works great when the list is passed directly as `funs`. However, it doesn't work if I save the list first in an object (`l_funs <- list(mean = mean, min = "min", sd, function(x) x^2)`) and pass it then to `foo3` (`foo3(1:5, l_funs)`). Error: `object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable`. Is there an easy fix for this? I tried playing around with `eval`, `enquo`, etc., but can't figure it out.

Comment: You have to decide on whether you want unevaluated or evaluated arguments.  You can do `foo2(1:5, l_funs)` or `do.call("foo3", list(1:5, l_funs))`

Answer (score 2):

One thing that you are missing is replacing the `for` loops with `lapply`. Also for functional programming it is often good practice to separate functions to do one thing. I personally like the version from solution 1 where you pass the functions in directly because it avoids another call in R and therefore is more efficient. In solution 2, it is best to use `match.fun` instead of `get`. `match.fun` is stricter than `get` in searching for functions.

```
x <- 1:5

foo <- function(input, funs) {
  lapply(funs, function(fun) fun(input))
}

foo(x, c(mean=mean, min=min))
```

The above code simplifies your solution 1. To add to this function, you could add some error handling such as `is.numeric` for x and `is.function` for funs.